# How to add primefaces button hover effect to an html button

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I have an html `<button>` and styled it as per primefaces `<p:commandButton>`. But I'm not getting the hover and active effect. I have tried adding the effect using javascript onmouse over but still can't get it.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('ui-state-hover')" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover')" onmousedown="$(this).addClass('ui-state-active')">
       <h:outputText styleClass="ui-button-text" value="Login" />
</button>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: are trying to add this feature via jquery/javascript or just css? where is your jquery/javascript code?

Comment: I'm using Primefaces component library which has its own built-in css and j-query library. These features are already built in the library, so when I use <p:commandButton> I can get the full effects. However, I need to use those styles on an HTML button. I can't get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding onmouseup, it works on my project;

```
<input jsfc="h:commandButton"
    class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only yourCSSClass"
    onmouseover="$(this).addClass('ui-state-hover')"
    onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover')"
    onmousedown="$(this).addClass('ui-state-active')"
    onmouseup="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-active')"
    value="New Button" onclick="alert('Hello World!');">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
</input>
```